# How to link Route53 purchased domain to Elastic IP in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

After creating an EC2 Instance hosting a website and linking it to an Elastic IP (which works) I have spent the last 3 days attempting to link a domain I purchased on Route53 with the Elastic IP. I’ve already followed the documentation for creating a resource record set. That didn’t help. In the “Hosted Zone” for the domain when I click the domain a notification below the 4 name servers in the right panel states that I must update the current DNS service or registrar for the Domain with the name server records for the Route53 Hosted Zone. How is this done? I’ve already created a resource record set, thoroughly read the pertinent AWS Documentation. Googled endlessly.

TL;DR I purchased the Domain through AWS but can’t figure out how to “update the name server records with the current DNS service or registrar.”

Willing to Bitcoin tip / Changetip anyone who can help me figure this out.

Comment: Didn't realize Bitcoin Tipping does not work here. If you help me resolve this I'll tip you $5 on a reddit post of your choice to your account.

Comment: Can you attached a picture of your Route53 record set for this domain?

Comment: Yes here it is: http://i.imgur.com/ageTlP5.jpg and here are the 4 name servers listed http://truculentgoats.imgur.com/all/

Comment: is the A record at the top your elastic IP?

Comment: In the AWS Console on the Elastic IP page I can find nothing resembling an A record? What is this A record?

Comment: your "truculent" URL isn't visible now, but it was the top record in Route53. Roughly, copy the IP address from the Elastic IP page to a new record (Type: A) in your domain zone (in rt53). If you need more help, I can expand that into a full answer, just tell me where you're having difficulty.

Comment: http://imgur.com/ageTlP5    Yes I see what you mean by A record. I followed the documentation instructions for creating a new resource record set like that which included entering the Elastic IP into the A record. Didn't work. Tried it several times. Specifically this, " Before the Domain Name System will start to route queries for this domain to Route 53 name servers, you must update the name server records either with the current DNS service or with the registrar for the domain, as applicable. For more information, see Help." is the thing that I can not figure out how to do.

Comment: The "must update" message normally appears when defining a hosted zone via the "Create Hosted Zone" button, but should not appear if you used the "Register Domain" function (which costs money). Did you follow the procedure show here? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingNewDNS.html

Comment: I did follow those procedures. Purchased the domain through Route53. Configured the DNS for my domain by creating a resource record set. Didn't work. I've actually purchased another domain for $12, followed the instructions exactly again, have tried fiddling with the record set for days. Completely at a loss. Considering spending $50 a month for AWS technical support but really don't want to.

Comment: If you were willing to tell us the actual domain name, and shows us the full records, we could probably fix you up in no time. It isn't/shouldn't be hard - I have about 50 domains routed the route53 and its usually as easy as 1-2-3, (and almost that quick) so you may have just missed a small but important step.

Comment: How could providing the domain name, hosted zone ID # and 4 name server records help you fix this? I've been under the impression that a small but important step is what I am missing but am so far completely unaware of even where this step could be located. I have been under the impression that creating an A record set with the Elastic IP would solve the problem of the DNS routing queries for my domain to the Elastic IP but I guess its something else...

Comment: Guys what exactly does this mean? "* Before the Domain Name System will start to route queries for this domain to Route 53 name servers, you must update the name server records either with the current DNS service or with the registrar for the domain." As it seems to be the problem. How do I solve it? Apparently creating a Resource Record Set with the A-IPv4 address does not fix this problem.

Comment: Create a new record set with www.yourdomain.com and select alias yes, select yourdomain.com in alias target. Make sure yourdomain.com routing to your public domain

Comment: Why is this being answered in comments and not as a proper "Answer"?